# Ist der Satz "Das behaupten nur wir" richtig?

Tags: word-order, subject, heidegger

Wenn beim Hauptsatz das Subjekt nicht an erster Position steht, dann sollte es in der dritten Position stehen. Das weiß ich.
Also was wäre die Erklärung für diesen Satz? "Das behaupten nur wir." 
Es ist ein Satz des deutschen Philosophen Martin Heidegger.

Comment: Was ist in der Regel, die Du zitierst, mit *Position* und *Subjekt* gemeint? In z.B. ‚Die drei kleinen Schweinchen hatten große Angst‘, gilt ‚Die drei kleinen Schweinchen‘ als das Subjekt, oder nur das Nomen ‚Schweinchen‘? An welcher Stelle steht ‚Die drei kleinen Schweinchen‘ im Satz – an der ersten, oder ersten bis vierten?

Comment: @MarkOxford, natürlich weiß ich, dass die erste Position aus mehreren Wörtern bestehen kann. Bei meinem Beispiel habe ich mir gedacht,"nur" ein Adverbialbestimmung wäre. Jetzt ist aber alles Klar.

Comment: @JanDoggen, Martin Heidegger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die *Positionen* beziehen sich auf Satzbausteine, nicht auf einzelne Wörter. Ein Satzbaustein kann durchaus aus mehreren Wörtern bestehen. Das ist sogar der Normalfall.

> Das – behaupten – nur wir.

Das Subjekt ist **Nur wir**, nicht *wir*.

Comment: Ich dachte "nur" ein Adverbialbestummung wäre. Deswegen ein anderer Satzglied als das Subjekt.

Comment: Mit adverbialer Bestimmung müsste man es **Das behaupten wir nur.** schreiben. Tipp: Adverbiale Bestimmungen stehen meist zwischen Objekten/Subjekt und dem zweiten Teil des finiten Verbs, sollte einer da sein, sonst am Satzende. Das hängt damit zusammen, dass sie ja die Aktion des Satzes genauer beschreiben, nicht ein Objekt oder das Subjekt.

Answer (score 3):

Die Standardform der Aussage ist:

> Nur wir - behaupten - das.

Subjekt - Verb - Objekt

"Nur" bezieht sich auf "Wir". Ein andere Bedeutung gewinnt der Satz wenn wir das "nur" auf "das" beziehen.

> Wir - behaupten - nur das.

Wir können das Objekt im Deutschen an den Anfang stellen, um es zu betonen
Das - behaupten - nur wir.

Und erhalten den zitierten Satz.